# Windows Form freezing on show()

Tags: c#, winforms, freeze

Having a problem with my windows form. It's a very basic windows form, called from a seperate class. It has 1 button and 1 textfield. It takes 1 argument of a client

```
var form = new Form1(client);

form.Show();
```

Form1 code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DiscordClient client;

    public Form1(DiscordClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var usernameToKick = username.Text;

        var userToKick = client.Servers.FirstOrDefault().Users.Where(input => input.Name == usernameToKick).FirstOrDefault();

        userToKick.Kick();
    }

    private void username_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

This freezes my form for about 30 seconds, before the form shuts down again.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Something is wrong in `Form1`'s initialization code, which we cannot see. Do note that a thread can only do one thing at a time, so if `Form1` does something computationally intensive when it loads, your entire application will freeze while that computation takes place.

Comment: Updated with form1's code

Comment: Based on `Form1` code I can't find anything wrong with its initialization. Might be some kind of an issue with your `client` instance. Can you try: `DiscordClient client = null;` `var form = new Form1(client);` `form.Show();` and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: Debug your project by setting some breakpoints - or Console.WriteLine(...) instructions-, to identify the time-consuming part of your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Form form;


form = new Form1(client, e);

            var thread = new Thread(OpenAdminPanel);

            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();


private void OpenAdminPanel()
    {
        Application.Run(AdminPanel);
    }
```

Comment: It did fix my problem though